# Angular: Provide same instance for multiple tokens

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to do something like this:

```
{
  provide: [Token1, Token2],
  useClass: MyService,
},
```

Something which I would do with Autofac in .Net like `containerBuilder.Register<MyService>().As<IService1>().As<IService2>()`. The instance of the object requested via both tokens should be the same. Is it possible with angular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one.

{ provide: Token1, useClass: MyService}
 { provide: Token2, useExisting: MyService}

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Answer (score 3):

To provide the same instance you can use `useExisting`

```
[
    { provide: Token1, useClass: MyService},
    { provide: Token2, useExisting: MyService}
]
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ExistingProvider